# Ошибка при использовании HtmlResponse.replace()

Tags: python, scrapy

Почему при замене меты в методе:

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    product = response.meta['product']
    .........
    new_meta= {}
    .........
    response = response.replace(meta=new_meta)
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'meta'
```

Python 2.7, Scrapy 0.24.4

Comment: Потому, что нет у Вас в респонсе ключевого слова `meta`

Comment: Я уверен что в респонсе мета есть. Она используется сразу же в начале метода (добавил строчку в вопрос)

Comment: а если попробовать так - `response.meta = new_meta` а можете еще добавить вывод `print(dir(response))`

Comment: нет, так это не работает ```exceptions.AttributeError: can't set attribute```

Comment: А если так:  `setattr(response, '_{class_name}__meta'.format(class_name=type(response).__name__),  new_meta)`

Comment: @AndrioSkur Ваш вариант сработал, спасибо. Так а почему все же не работает ```replace```?

Comment: Дайте полный traceback исключения

Answer (score 0):

parse_product это метод класса который является потомком scrapy.Spider? Если да то возможно вы переопределили метод **init**() и не сделали в нем вызов scrapy.Spider.**init**